# Rails 4 Active Admin, Attribute Won't Save

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently using rails 4 and active admin for my admin interface.  I have a profile which has many analytics_by_weeks.

```
   class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :analytics_by_weeks
```

I want to use active admin to create new analytics_by_weeks and link them to a profile (following my belongs_to has_many relationship),  but when I click create to generate the new analytics_by_week the profile attribute will not save.

In my program I added a name attribute to a profile:

```
    add_column :profile, :name, :string
```

I have tried making a custom formtastic form:

```
    f.input :profile, :collection => Profile.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }
```

Nothing has worked, what am I doing wrong?  I have also used permit parameters to permit profile, id, and name.

Comment: You're talking about three different parameters and possibly three different problems, here....

Comment: Do you add `permit_params profile_id` to your active admin resource? and `belongs_to profile` to your AnalyticsByWeek model?

Comment: @Aguardientico I thought I had, but I checked again and I did not.  Thank you, that fixed it